# How can i keep the Searched thing in search bar after searching something in Django?

Tags: python, django, search

Whenever i am searching for something in search bar. My search functionality is working properly but the thing i had searched gets disappear.

How can i keep the text in search bar after searching?

Comment: Presumably you have a view that handles the search string, why don't you just add the string to your context and render it in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Answer for completeness:

Pass the query string to your view context so that you can access it in your template:

```py
search_string = request.GET.get('q', '')

...

context = {
   'search_string': search_string,
   ...
}
```

Then in the template:

```html
<input type='text' name='search' value='{{ search_string }}'>
```